# Simple C++ code is skipping a line in text file

Tags: c++, debugging

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char *filename_param="Simion_PA_Config.txt";
int x_min,x_length,y_min,y_length,z_min,z_length;
ifstream file_param;

template <typename T> void GetParameterSkipLine(ifstream &file,T &parameter);

int main(){
    file_param.open(filename_param);
    if(!file_param){
        cout << "Couldn't open parameter file" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    GetParameterSkipLine(file_param,x_min);
    GetParameterSkipLine(file_param,x_length);
    GetParameterSkipLine(file_param,y_min);
    GetParameterSkipLine(file_param,y_length);
    GetParameterSkipLine(file_param,z_min);
    GetParameterSkipLine(file_param,z_length);
    cout << x_min << " " << y_min << " " << z_min << endl;
    cout << x_length << " " << y_length << " " << z_length << endl;
}

template <typename T> void GetParameterSkipLine(ifstream &file,T &parameter){
    string s;
    getline(file,s);
    stringstream line(s);
    file >> parameter;
}
```

Reading this file:

```
0                   !x_min //
150
0
40
0
300
5   1.2
10  1.3
15  0
5   15
2   20
```

Outputs:

```
150 40 300
0 0 5
```

Everything behaves as if it is skipping a line in my text file. Everything works if I add a bogus line. I have no idea what is going on.

I have tried remaking the text file, opening it in a different editor. I have stripped down my code to isolate the problem and compile just what you see above, the problem is still there.

Please help, I might start sorting in O(N^3) if this keeps chipping away at my sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
file >> parameter;
```

to

```
line >> parameter;
```

Comment: Of course, I've been using this function for months I don't know how and when I bugged it from line to file. I even checked it many times but somehow didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake there. You read a line from the file with 
    `string s;
    getline(file,s);`

Then you read the other line with

```
file >> parameter;
```

So basically, you throw away what you read into s.